# Where are the system files in a linux iso?

Tags: filesystems, kali-linux, iso

I'm trying to modify a linux kali iso… by changing images, icons, files, etc. etc.
 the only problem is that I don't know where the folders and the main applications are located in to an iso

Comment: You cannot change directly an ISO image, that's the whole concept of an ISO ...

Comment: Which files are you looking for? If you don't know how system files are layed out, then kali is not the distro for you. Please choose another Gnu/Linux distro such as Debian. Kali is for experienced Gnu/Linux users. It is also not a general purpose OS.

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is to dig into the process used to create the ISO image (don't know about Kali --I'm a Fedora user myself--, but the process to create a customized live image should be detailed somewhere). That will allow you to change much more than a set of configuration files: Add or remove packages, and so on.